# django channels app is blocking when handle many requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

i have a DRF project, using django channels, i have a endpoint that handles thousands requests for each 5seconds, sometimes this endpoint is blocking my app, what would be the best way to handle it.

some posts adivises to use `raise StopComsumer()` in the disconect method, but not resolve, im getting this error

```
server 14128 15048 Application instance <Task pending name='Task-36' coro=<ASGIStaticFilesHandler.__call__() running at D:\DevTrust\gotvee\seeligg\seeligg\api\seeligg_api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py:101> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future
```

this is my consumer

```
class ChargerSessionConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(args, kwargs)
       self.client_id = None
       self.group_name = None

    async def connect(self):
       self.group_name = 'room'
       self.client_id = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["client_id"]

      await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.group_name, self.channel_name
      )

      await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.client_id, self.channel_name
      )

      await self.accept()

async def websocket_disconnect(self, message):
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.group_name, self.channel_name
    )

    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.client_id, self.channel_name
    )

    raise StopConsumer()
```